# Hook into Panels content form submit

Tags: hooks, panels

I'm writing a routine to track inline image usage in panel panes every time the panels content form is submitted. The *hook_panels_pane_update* hook works, but only after the second time the form is saved. Is there a hook that will trigger the first time the form is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, according to the `panels.api.php` file, hook_panels_pane_update() is for *changed* panes.  There's one just above it for new panes called hook_panels_pane_insert().

If you want the same function to happen every time regardless of whether the pane is new or not, combine them like this:

```
function mymodule_panels_pane_insert($pane){
  mymodule_act_on_panels($pane);
}

function mymodule_panels_pane_update($pane){
  mymodule_act_on_panels($pane);
}

function mymodule_act_on_panels($pane){
  //Do the things here
}
```